# What difference does "up" make in these cases?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

How do these sentences work? Is there any difference? Sorry if it's obvious, I'm not a native speaker.

> He stitched me up.

and

> He stitched me.

I'm using the verb *stitch*, but it could be other verbs or tenses. Other examples:

> He calls me X He calls me up
>
> She showed in the room X She showed up in the room.
>
> She beat the enemy X She beat up the enemy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adverbial particle "up" sometimes merely completes the sense of the verb. This is the case with "stitch somebody up." While "stitch somebody" is not idiomatic, "stitch somebody up" is.

In other cases, "up" is used to mean "completely," as in "He ate it **up**."

In the other three sentences you mention, adding "up" leads to the formation of a phrasal verb:

- call somebody **up**: call somebody on the phone
- show **up**: appear
- beat **up**: hit severely

Notice that the verbs *call, show, beat* alone do not carry the more specific meanings mentioned above.